# Undefined variable $output in Symfony Component Console DialogHelper

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2, symfony-2.3

I tried to run symfony console command, but I've got an error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: output in /var/www/.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/DialogHelper.php line 411
```

I have no idea, why it went wrong.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to migrate to Symfony 2.3 as it is a LTS version.

Comment: Maybe i'll try later, because i have many deprecated methods, which Symfony 2.3 not support.

Comment: @Florent I have migrate to Symfony 2.3.3 but unfortunately i have the same error.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your `composer.json` file?

Comment: Try to change `minimum-stability` to `alpha` and then run `composer update`. **You're vendors seems to be outdated.**

Comment: @Florent I have update all vendors - no changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem: this error appears because `exec()` and `shell_exec` functions was disabled in `php.ini` file. To enable this functions you have to edit this string:

`disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open`

and delete `exec`, `shell_exec`:

`disable_functions =passthru,system,proc_open`