# Symfony2 - generate:bundle command throws Notice: Undefined variable: output

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, bundle

I'm new to Symfony2 framework and following an online tut. However, when I reached the point to setting up a bundle in CMD following message repeatedly appearing.

```
Configuration format (annotation, yaml, xml, php) [annotation]: Notice: Undefined variable: output
```

Does anyone encontered similar problem? (see the screen shot)[image]

Comment: have you tried php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/Bundle/BlogBundle --no-interaction

Comment: Seems to be a nervous error level setting of your php.exe ..
did you try to enter one of the choices in the last line - for example xml?
That command should nonetheless successful create your bundle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears because you disabled `exec` and/or `shell_exec` in your **php.ini**. To debug run one of the following commands:

```
# linux/osx
php -i | grep 'disable_functions'
# windows
php -i | findstr 'disable_functions'
```

If the `disable_functions` ini-directive contains *exec* or **shell_exec** ...

```
disable_functions=exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open
```

... remove them from `disable_functions` in your CLI's **php.ini** as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142343/undefined-variable-output-in-symfony-component-console-dialoghelper).